# PRTG: I have some errors but I don't have any idea about the meaning and how can i resolve these pb

Tags: prtg

any idea about tis error: The sensor could not find any matching data on the target device. To resolve this issue, check if the target device meets the requirements and if the required OIDs are reachable. (code: PE187)

No idea about the problem

Comment: What type of sensor is this, and if not the default, what it is testing for? Eg specific sensor values, or a specific string returned by the remote machine etc?